# Different values in keyframes for Cycles then for Eevee?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, keyframes

When using IES files, spot lights in Cycles need just minimal power value, as the IES contains the intensity, but for Eevee, spot lights need full power of the light for the (volumetric) beams to be visible.

How would I be animating and saving keyframes in Eevee but rendering in Cycles when each of them need different values in the keyframes. Is this possible to do? I store the keyframes with python, so programmatic solution is ok... Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you have keyframes on the strength of some lights, and you need that strength to be, let's say, 10 times higher in Eevee than in Cycles ? I could show you a way with drivers, a bit clumsy but it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are keyframing the Power value of the light, you can drive a Value in the material editor with it to control IES light intensity.

Right click over the Power value > Copy as New Driver.

In the Material editor Right click over a Value node > Paste Driver.

From here you can insert whatever math operation you like to set a intensity ratio between Eevee and Cycles.

[image]

In the example the IES intensity is 1/4000 the Power of the light (driven value).

Comment: Thank you very much!